# mysql WHERE CLAUSE to exclude rows based on two different values in same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using [MySQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/mysql/mysql-data-compare/) to compare a local & remote mysql db.
I'm trying to setup a simple WHERE clause that excludes any rows from the comparison that contain the following values:

`%mm` or `%transient%`

The WHERE clause i'm using doesn't seem to be working.

`'option_name' NOT LIKE '%_transient_%' OR '%mm%'`

The full query that's running is:

```
SELECT 'option_id', 'option_name', 'option_value', 'autoload' 
FROM 'wp_options WHERE 'option_name' NOT LIKE '%_transient_%' OR '%mm%'
```

And the resulting output does not exclude the rows that that have `mm` or `_transient_` in the option_name column.

The caveat here is that I'm limited to only using a WHERE clause & I'm not able to edit the SELECT clause leading up to it (as that's all generated by the software).

Comment: it should be `option_name NOT LIKE '%_transient_%' AND  option_name NOT LIKE '%mm%'`.also don't use single-quotes for column names as they will be treated as string constants. use backticks (in mysql) or double-quotes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Comment: I don't know if this is a typo or not but the table name isn;t set off by quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no form of `LIKE` for comparing to multiple patterns.

As @vkp mentioned in a comment (I don't know why they don't post an answer), your condition won't do what you intend:

```
WHERE option_name NOT LIKE '%_transient_%' OR '%mm%'
```

It's not a syntax error in MySQL, because `OR` can use any expression as operands. Zero values count as false, nonzero values count as true. So your condition is equivalent to:

```
WHERE (option_name NOT LIKE '%_transient_%') OR ('%mm%')
```

Which is logically equivalent to:

```
WHERE (option_name NOT LIKE '%_transient_%') OR (true)
```

Which will be true on every row, because a true value `OR`'d together with any other expression will result in true.

Your condition should be this:

```
WHERE option_name NOT LIKE '%_transient_%' AND option_name NOT LIKE '%mm%'
```

Comment: Excellent explanation.  At first, using AND seemed counter-intuitive.  But your logical equivalency example makes sense why it'd be AND instead of OR.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's a good idea to be fluent with boolean algebra. `(NOT A) AND (NOT B)` is equal to `NOT (A OR B)`.